# Authentication based upon security group

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication

I am trying to authenticate a user based upon a security group present in the database.

I am using `System.Web.Security.Users.IsUserInRole(string rolename)` inside `Page_Load()`.

Even though the user is part of the security group, the user is not authenticated.

I don't know where I am going wrong. I have enabled `roleManager` in `web.config`.

Every single iteration of the code prints '**User is not authenticated**'.

I'm trying to access this code from my local machine, which is a part of the client corporate network, in which the security group too exists.

PFB the code:

`WebForm1.aspx.cs`:

```
SqlConnection xconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectToDB"].ToString());
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = getData();
    string securityGroup = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();//**securityGroup=Redmond\\myTeam**
    if (System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(securityGroup))
    {
        Response.Write("User is authenticated");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("User is not authenticated");
    }
}
public DataTable getData()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Sample.dbo.ReportConfig", xconn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

`Web.Config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="Default">
        <providers>
          <add name="Default" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
        </providers>
      </roleManager>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectToDB" connectionString="Data Source=Dev-PC;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use `IsUserInRole()` to check if a user is in an Active Directory (or similar) group? Because if so, that wont work. `IsUserInRole()` checks against the membership DB.

Comment: Yes, am trying to do so. How to make it work though? Any suggestions?

Comment: What is passed as argument to IsUserInRole? It's can't such string as in comment - it's not valid.

Comment: @rufanov: Redmond\\myTeam is passed, which is the correct security group fetched from the DB. If its not valid, then what kind of stuffs would be valid. Can you shed some light?

Comment: @chrfin, `IsUserInRole()` checks against the configured role provider which, if I'm not mistaken, can be AD and it's definitely not DB-only.

Comment: True and I did not know, but by default it does. The OP found it out already according to his comments below...

Comment: @chrfin, the web.config fragment in the post shows the [WindowsTokenRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kfktzx5w.aspx "WindowsTokenRoleProvider Class") configured as the role provider.

Comment: You learn something new every day, thanks ;-)...

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole` to check against AD groups by default. This method checks against the membership database in the default configuration. One way of working around this, is the following and I used it in an application of mine successfully:

Copy the groups from each AD user to the membership DB on Login. This of course has the downside, that role changes are only detected at login of the user:

```
var user = model.UserName.Split('\\');
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, user[0]))
{
    if (pc.ValidateCredentials(user[1], model.Password, ContextOptions.Negotiate))
    {
        using (var adUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, user[1]))
        {
            if (!MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                using (var _userDb = new UsersDbContext())
                {
                    if (_userDb.aspnet_Users.Count(u => u.UserName.ToLower().Contains(model.UserName)) <= 0)
                    {
                        MembershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, adUser.EmailAddress);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var msUser = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
                        msUser.ChangePassword(msUser.ResetPassword(), model.Password);
                    }
                }
            }
            FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

            foreach (var role in Roles.GetAllRoles())
            {
                if (role == LoginRoles.Customer)
                    continue;

                using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, role))
                {
                    if (group != null)
                    {
                        if (adUser.IsMemberOf(group))
                        {
                            if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, role))
                                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, role);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, role))
                                Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(model.UserName, role);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my case the groups from the AD are already present in the membership DB. If they are not in your case, you would need to create or sync them too.

Another approach would be to create your own role provider, which queries the AD on every call (**maybe there is already one available**). I used the approach from above, because I had mixed users, where only some of the users from the application where also AD members. I used the `\` to distinguish between them. As soon as a user is login in with e.g. `DOMAIN\user` and not just `user` I query the AD with above code.

Comment: Thank you..I understood bits and pieces. I would try to implement them in my code.

Comment: I added the security group inside my Administrators group, and then did allow roles="Redmond\myTeam", hosted the application on IIS, did windows authentication as true. The app works now.

Comment: chrfin, IsUserInRole() checks against the configured role provider which, if I'm not mistaken, can be AD and it's definitely not DB-only.